# Pandas: create a group ID that increments based on multiple criteria

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataset as below (sorted chronologically) and I would like to create a group ID (desired ID) by Analyst and Stock that increments whenever the stock went from either long or short to neutral or when the stock went from long to short (or vice versa). In words, the ID is for an Analyst's idea on a stock where idea is defined by crossing the neutral line which is in the middle of long and short. Your help would be much appreciated.

[image]

Adding more details:
The dataset contains records with analyst, stock, conviction, side, entry date and exit date, last two fields omitted for brevity and dataset is ordered by Analyst-Stock-EntryDate in chronological order. The goal is to create an identifier for analyst-stock ideas, where an idea is defined as going from long to neutral, short to neutral but also long to short and short to long, the last two effectively cross the neutral bucket, for instance going from long to short is considered as going from long to neutral (an idea) and neutral to short (another idea).

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Analyst': ['John'] * 5 + ['Sara'] * 9, 'Stock': ['AAA'] * 5 + ['BBB'] * 3 + ['CCC'] * 3 + ['DDD'] * 3,
                        'Conviction': ['strong', 'mid', 'neutral', 'mid', 'neutral', 'mid', 'mid', 'neutral', 'strong', 'mid', 'neutral', 'mid', 'mid', 'neutral'],
                        'Side': ['long', 'long', 'neutral', 'short', 'neutral', 'long', 'short', 'neutral', 'short', 'short', 'neutral', 'short', 'long', 'neutral'],
                        'Desired_ID': ['1']*3 + ['2']*2 + ['1'] + ['2']*2 + ['1']*3 + ['1'] + ['2']*2})
```

Comment: plz provide text of example, not image. and provice your desired output

Comment: Why is your result not `1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1` given it's supposed to be grouped by analyst and stock?

Comment: @Nick fair observation, I have edited the question and desired ID

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you could use a custom [`groupby.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) and [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
cat = pd.CategoricalDtype(categories=['short', 'neutral', 'long'], ordered=True)

s = df['Side'].astype(cat)
m1 = s.ge('neutral')
m2 = s.le('neutral')
m3 = s.ne('neutral')

df['idx'] = (m2.groupby([df['Analyst'], df['Stock']])
               .transform(lambda x: (x.shift().fillna(x).eq(m1)&m3).cumsum()+1)
             )
```

Output:

```
   Analyst Stock Conviction     Side Desired_ID  idx
0     John   AAA     strong     long          1    1
1     John   AAA        mid     long          1    1
2     John   AAA    neutral  neutral          1    1
3     John   AAA        mid     long          2    2
4     John   AAA    neutral  neutral          2    2
5     Sara   BBB        mid     long          1    1
6     Sara   BBB        mid    short          2    2
7     Sara   BBB    neutral  neutral          2    2
8     Sara   CCC     strong    short          1    1
9     Sara   CCC        mid    short          1    1
10    Sara   CCC    neutral  neutral          1    1
11    Sara   DDD        mid    short          1    1
12    Sara   DDD        mid     long          2    2
13    Sara   DDD    neutral  neutral          2    2
```

Intermediates:

```
   Analyst Stock Conviction     Side Desired_ID  idx     m1     m2 m2_shift
0     John   AAA     strong     long          1    1   True  False      NaN
1     John   AAA        mid     long          1    1   True  False    False
2     John   AAA    neutral  neutral          1    1   True   True    False
3     John   AAA        mid     long          2    2   True  False     True
4     John   AAA    neutral  neutral          2    2   True   True    False
5     Sara   BBB        mid     long          1    1   True  False      NaN
6     Sara   BBB        mid    short          2    2  False   True    False
7     Sara   BBB    neutral  neutral          2    2   True   True     True
8     Sara   CCC     strong    short          1    1  False   True      NaN
9     Sara   CCC        mid    short          1    1  False   True     True
10    Sara   CCC    neutral  neutral          1    1   True   True     True
11    Sara   DDD        mid    short          1    1  False   True      NaN
12    Sara   DDD        mid     long          2    2   True  False     True
13    Sara   DDD    neutral  neutral          2    2   True   True    False
```

Variant for older pandas versions (python ≥ 3.8):

```
cat = pd.CategoricalDtype(categories=['short', 'neutral', 'long'], ordered=True)
s = df['Side'].astype(cat)

df['idx'] = (s.groupby([df['Analyst'], df['Stock']])
              .transform(lambda x: ((m:=x.le('neutral')).shift()
                                    .fillna(m)
                                    .eq(x.ge('neutral'))
                                    & x.ne('neutral')
                                   ).cumsum()+1
                       )
            )
```

Comment: Your solution is close but ignores the fact that going from long to short (or short to long) effectively crosses the neutral mark in this use case

Comment: Thanks. Looks like your code is getting the right IDs, what pandas version are you using? I get the following error: NameError: name 'cat' is not defined

Comment: @user99 forgot to copy one line ;)

Comment: thanks! but still cannot reproduce your results, I get following error: ValueError: Length of passed values is 14, index implies 5. My pandas versions is '1.1.5'. What's your version?

Comment: I'm using 2.0.3, what is the complete error message? which line triggers it?

Comment: Error occurs when '.eq(m1)&m3' is introduced, if excluded then no error but (obviously) results are not as expected. Any hint of the root cause?

Comment: OK, I see why, which python version do you have? Check the update, I provided an alternative (untested, but hopefully should work)

Comment: I tried below just to get any additional color `(m2.groupby([df['Analyst'], df['Stock']]).transform(lambda x: (x.shift().fillna(x).eq(m1.values)).cumsum()+1))` and got ValueError: Lengths must be equal

Comment: Have you tried the alternative version?

Comment: Thanks, I tried it and it worked, however I noticed the proposed solution is not capturing well cases where ideas go from short to neutral (I suspect because of the order assigned), for instance if you replace the fourth item in the 'Side' field from long to short, the ID is expected to be the same as is a new idea that started short. So starting long or short should be treated the same, they are both new stock ideas. What do you think?

Comment: Can you update your example? I purposely mask the case that go to "neutral" as it was my understanding they are a not match

Comment: just updated the example, long to neutral and short to neutral are both desired to be identified (Desired_ID) as independent stock ideas

Comment: wondering if you found a way to handle the new example?

Comment: @user99 how should it behave if you have two "neutral" in a row?

Comment: the "neutral" that matters is "Side" field, the "neutral" in "Conviction" field is not informative i.e. one cannot be very neutral or mid neutral, just neutral so technically those can be translated to NaN, what matters is identifying ideas by "Side" transition: long to neutral, short to neutral, long to short (can be thought as long to neutral and a new short) and short to long (can be thought as short to neutral, and a new long)

Comment: just checking if you had a chance to look at my last comment, regards